dbatools None of the commands are working, Getting error message network path was not found
dbatools None of the commands are working, Getting error message network path was not found. I tried to run a basic command
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance sql01 -Database Master -query 'SELECT GETDATE()'
WARNING: [11:27:29][Invoke-DbaQuery] Failure | The network path was not found


Your SQLInstance is wrong.   Best way of debugging is to use SQL Server Management Studio.  Get connection working with SSMS.  The instance with SSMS (shown on login window) is the same as with Invoke-dbaQuery.
